# How to include a certificate in a jar keystore

Tags: maven, jar, ssl-certificate, keystore

I  would like to know if there is way to add a certificate file (.cer) to a jar keystore while building the jar with maven
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the resource folder. Will be available on the classpath as a resource.